# Customise ANTD Date picker in react

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, antd, ant-design-pro

[image]

Hello I'm building a form component but for date picker i want to use date picker of ant design, so i customizing my date picker component, but it's blue outline is not being changed, that blue outline is visible when hover or when i focus on field, Also help me if i can change color of other part like that **"Today"** color in calendar

Here is my code I used tailwind css i want that border or it's outline to be of black

```
import React from "react";
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';

const DatePickers = (props) => {
  const { formik, title, name, Icon, minDate, maxDate } = props;

  return (
    <div className="mb-2">
      <span className="flex">
        {Icon}
        <label
          htmlFor={name}
          className="block text-sm font-semibold text-textPrimary dark:text-dark_textPrimary"
        >
          {title}
        </label>
      </span>
      <span className="flex w-full">
        <DatePicker
          type="date"
          name={name}
          bordered={true}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          placeholder={title}
          min={minDate} 
          max={maxDate}
          className={`block w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-textPrimary dark:text-dark_textPrimary bg-background  focus:border-black focus:outline-black dark:bg-dark_background border-2 rounded-md focus:ring-0 ring-0 border-cardBorder dark:border-dark_cardBorder 
            ${
            formik.touched[name] && formik.errors[name]
              ? "border-error_red placeholder-error_red"
              : "outline-cardBorder dark:outline-dark_cardBorder "
              }
        `}
        />
      </span>
      {formik.touched[name] && formik.errors[name] && (
        <h3 className="text-xs text-error_red">{formik.errors[name]}</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DatePickers;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blue line or `Today` blue color is inherited from [`ConfigProvider`](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) theme, `token.colorPrimary` to be more specific. Changing this color prop you'll change your whole app primary color.

If you want to change only datepicker color specific you should then change `components.DatePicker` color props. You can see all available changeable options, test and preview changes inside [theme editor](https://ant.design/theme-editor).

Or, in worse case, you can change these styles using css classes. In this case you'll need to use dev console to search for the class you'll want to change.

Comment: Thanks It worked 

```
import { ConfigProvider } from "antd";
      <ConfigProvider
       theme={{
      token: {
        colorPrimary: '#00b96b',
      }
       }}
      >
  ...
```


I did this but what if i want only want to change only that border color or that outline color?? If you have any idea?

Comment: Then you'll need to do as I say in second part of my answer. Change your config provider to something like this: `<ConfigProvider theme={{ components: {DatePicker: { colorPrimary: '#00b96b'}} }} >`  Use theme editor to see/test other colors props you'll can change.